# Create Jar With External Jar Libraries (Intellij 2017)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I created a simple application using IntelliJ.I exported my project to a jar file and Every Thing was fine and jar file worked properly. Now I decide to use jfoenix.jar in my project for button and text fields.I add a jfoenix to my project and it works fine in the intellij environment but when I export my project to the jar it doesn't work(I click on the jar file which is created and nothing happens).
I know my problem is related to the jfoenix.jar library because it seems that it doesn't attach to my project properly but I don't know how to attach external libraries like jfoenix.jar to my project for creating a jar file of the project.
Maybe I did something wrong in my steps.

I follow below steps to create jar in IntelliJ:

> 1-Project Structure->build artifact->select the main class->Ok.
>
> 2-Build->Build Artifacts

Comment: Before we answer, what do you have in your Manifest inside the jar? (unzip it and see)

Comment: @CrazyCoder where is the original?

Comment: @tcs it's linked at the top of the question.